# What is the best way to summarize interval data?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Given data in a table with arbitrary intervals (NOT date/time!!) defined as follows:

```
START float
END float
VALUE varchar(40)
```

E.g.

```
 START    END    VALUE
 -----    ---    ------
 0        1      Banana
 1        3      Banana
 3        4      Orange
 4        7      Orange
 7        8      Apple
 8        9      Apple
 9       10      Apple
10       15      Apple
20       22      Apple
22       23      Apple
23       28      Banana
28       30      Banana
etc..
```

How do I summarize the data so that for continguous intervals, only one value is listed. I.e. the result of the query should look like:

```
START     END    VALUE
-----     ---    ------
 0        3      Banana
 3        7      Orange
 7       15      Apple
20       23      Apple
23       30      Banana
```

Note the gap between 15 and 20 above. I'm dealing with quite a lot of data (~500k rows), but not running the query frequently. So efficiency is nice-to-have. Can this be done without use of a cursor?

(Note: Using SQL2008R2 so can't take advantage of newer features, if they exist)

Thanks!

Comment: This is why this site remains a go-to place for me. After just a couple of hours I have several great responses. Thanks all! I'll try to wrap my head around the various options and will upvote/accept accordingly soon.

Comment: Couldn't agree more, putting my answer aside, the others are fantastic.

Comment: All good answers, thank you! I'm not qualified to comment on the elegance/efficieny of the various options, so I accepted @adrianm's answer because of those I could adapt to my needs, his worked the fastest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH TableWithPreviousAndNext AS (
    SELECT CA1.[Previous]
          ,Table1.[Start]
          ,Table1.[End]
          ,CA2.[Next]
          ,Table1.[Value]
          ,(1 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Value] ORDER BY Table1.[Start])) / 2 AS [Group]
    FROM Table1
         CROSS APPLY (
             SELECT MAX([End]) AS [Previous]
             FROM Table1 AS InnerTable1
             WHERE InnerTable1.[Value] = Table1.[Value]
                   AND InnerTable1.[Start] < Table1.[Start]
         ) AS CA1
         CROSS APPLY (
             SELECT MIN([Start]) AS Next
             FROM Table1 AS InnerTable1
             WHERE InnerTable1.[Value] = Table1.[Value]
                   AND InnerTable1.[Start] > Table1.[Start]
         ) AS CA2
        CROSS APPLY ( -- A little trick to create a 2 row group for isolated rows
            SELECT 1 AS Dummy
          UNION ALL
            SELECT 1
            WHERE ([Previous] IS NULL OR [Previous] <> [Start])
                  AND ([Next] IS NULL OR [Next] <> [End])
        ) AS CA3
    WHERE [Previous] IS NULL -- Remove all but first and last in sequence
          OR [Next] IS NULL
          OR [Previous] <> [Start]
          OR [End] <> [Next]
)
SELECT MIN([Start])
      ,MAX([End])
      ,[Value]
FROM TableWithPreviousAndNext
GROUP BY [Value]
        ,[Group]
ORDER BY MIN(Start)
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Start INT, [End] INT, Value VARCHAR(100));
INSERT @T (Start, [End], Value)
VALUES
    (0, 1, 'Banana'), (1, 3, 'Banana'), (3, 4, 'Orange'), (4, 7, 'Orange'),
    (7, 8, 'Apple'), (8, 9, 'Apple'), (9, 10, 'Apple'), (10, 15, 'Apple'), 
    (20, 22, 'Apple'), (22, 23, 'Apple'), (23, 28, 'Banana'), (28, 30, 'Banana');

WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  t.[Start], 
            t.[End], 
            t.[value], 
            IsStart = ISNULL(c.IsStart, 1)
    FROM    @T AS T
            OUTER APPLY
            (   SELECT  TOP 1 IsStart = 0
                FROM    @T AS T2
                WHERE   T2.Value = T.Value
                AND     T2.[End] = T.Start
            ) AS c
)
SELECT  Value, Start = MIN(Start), [End] = MAX([End])
FROM    CTE AS T
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  SUM(IsStart)
            FROM    CTE AS T2
            WHERE   T2.Value = T.Value
            AND     T2.Start <= T.Start
        ) g (GroupingSet)
GROUP BY Value, GroupingSet
ORDER BY Start;
```

The first step is to identify each record that is the start of a new range. This part:

```
SELECT  t.[Start], 
        t.[End], 
        t.[value], 
        IsStart = ISNULL(c.IsStart, 1)
FROM    @T AS T
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 IsStart = 0
            FROM    @T AS T2
            WHERE   T2.Value = T.Value
            AND     T2.[End] = T.Start
        ) AS c
```

Will give:

```
Start   End value   IsStart
0       1   Banana  1
1       3   Banana  0
3       4   Orange  1
4       7   Orange  0
7       8   Apple   1
8       9   Apple   0
9       10  Apple   0
10      15  Apple   0
20      22  Apple   1
```

Then you can create unique groups by identifying the number of ranges that start before the current record, essentially adding a running total of the `IsStart` column partitioned by value. This is what is being done here:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    CTE AS T
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  SUM(IsStart)
            FROM    CTE AS T2
            WHERE   T2.Value = T.Value
            AND     T2.Start <= T.Start
        ) g (GroupingSet);
```

Giving:

```
Start   End value   IsStart GroupingSet
0       1   Banana  1       1
1       3   Banana  0       1
3       4   Orange  1       1
4       7   Orange  0       1
7       8   Apple   1       1
8       9   Apple   0       1
9       10  Apple   0       1
10      15  Apple   0       1
20      22  Apple   1       2   -- SECOND NON CONTINUOUS RANGE FOR APPLES
22      23  Apple   0       2
23      28  Banana  1       2   -- SECOND NON CONTINUOUS RANGE FOR BANANAS
28      30  Banana  0       2
```

Finally you can aggregate grouping by value, and this identifier column to identify unique groups.

You can also do this by expanding each range out into rows by cross joining to a numbers table (for brevity I have used `master..spt_values`):

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  t.[value], 
            Number = t.Start + v.Number,
            GroupingSet = t.Start + v.Number - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.[value] ORDER BY t.Start + v.Number)
    FROM    @T AS T
            INNER JOIN Master..spt_values v
                ON v.[Type] = 'P'
                AND v.Number < (t.[End] - t.[Start])
)
SELECT  Value, [Start] = MIN(Number), [End] = MAX(Number)
FROM    CTE
GROUP BY GroupingSet, Value;
```

The downfall of this is that it is likely to be quite memory intensive if you have a lot of rows/large ranges. After expanding the range this just uses the approach using ranking functions described in [Itzik Ben-Gan's Gaps and Islands Solutions](http://www.manning.com/nielsen/SampleChapter5.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I have a headache after this...

I couldn't work out a gaps/islands technique without expanding the data to contiguous row level data.

Here's my solution:

```
DECLARE @Fruits TABLE ([Start] FLOAT, [End] FLOAT, Value NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @Fruits
SELECT 0,1,'Banana' UNION
SELECT 1,3,'Banana' UNION
SELECT 3,4,'Orange' UNION
SELECT 4,7,'Orange' UNION
SELECT 7,8,'Apple' UNION
SELECT 8,9,'Apple' UNION
SELECT 9,10,'Apple' UNION
SELECT 10,15,'Apple' UNION
SELECT 20,22,'Apple' UNION
SELECT 22,23,'Apple' UNION
SELECT 23,28,'Banana' UNION
SELECT 28,30,'Banana'

;WITH ExpandCTE AS 
(
    SELECT 1 AS SPLITNUM,
           [End]-Start DURATION,
           Start,
           Start+1 AS [End],
           Value
    FROM @Fruits
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SPLITNUM+1,
           DURATION,
           Start+1 AS Start,
           Start+2 AS [End],
           Value
    FROM ExpandCTE
    WHERE SPLITNUM<DURATION
),
t1 AS
(
    SELECT *,
           START-ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY VALUE ORDER BY START) AS X
    FROM ExpandCTE
)

select MIN(Start) AS Start, MAX([End]) AS [End], Value
from t1
GROUP BY Value, X
ORDER BY Start
```

Comment: What is this `CASE WHEN [End]-Start=1 THEN 1 ELSE [End]-Start END AS DURATION,`?

Comment: Residual crap from testing!  Updating.

Answer (score 1):

With SQLServer 2008 one way of doing this is by using a triangular join, with a little twist

```
WITH I AS (
  SELECT ID = Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY Start)
       , _Start = [Start]
       , _End = [End]
       , Value
  FROM   Data
), D AS (
  SELECT i.ID, i._Start, i._End, i.Value
       , m.id _id, m.value _value
       , R = CASE WHEN i.Value <> m.Value THEN 1 
                  WHEN m._End <> i._Start THEN 1 
                  ELSE 0 
             END
  FROM   I
         CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1
                             id, _Start, _End, value
                      FROM   I m
                      WHERE  m.ID IN (i.ID, i.ID - 1)
                      ORDER BY ID) m
), B AS (
  SELECT i.ID, i._Start, i._End, i.Value
       , R = SUM(l.R)
  FROM   D i
         LEFT  JOIN D l ON i.id >= l.id
  GROUP BY i.ID, i._Start, i._End, i.Value
)
SELECT [START] = MIN(_Start)
     , [END] = MAX(_End)
     , Value
FROM   B
GROUP BY R, Value
ORDER BY 1
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9a34a/31)</kbd>

The `CTE` **`I`** (ID) creates an ID, that is needed to check whenever two following rows have a gap between them (the ID is used to get the correct row in the `JOIN`).

The `CTE` **`D`** (Data) uses the `CROSS APPLY` to get the previous row (or the same row for the first one) this is the same of `LAG`, the values of the previous row is checked to see if `Value` is changed or there is a gap between `[START]` of the current and `[END]` of the previous.

The `CTE` **`B`** (Block) uses the triangular `JOIN` between `D` and itself to create a field where are stored the number of changes and gap from the start to the current row, that field have the same number for the same group of data.

The main query uses that new column to aggregate the data.